# Implement group chat using ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd, chatroom, multiuserchat

I want to implement group chat like What's App
MUC(room chat) has some limitations:
1. user can not get the history of which rooms he has joined.
2. if the invited user is not online, then the user can not join the room and get the message.

Multi cast XEP-0033, seem good solution, but can not create the group concept, and the group history is lost when uninstall and re-install the client.

Any suggestion for implementing group chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMPP does not have the concept of whatsapp group as default. You need to roll out a custom approach to build it.

However, with the existing building bricks in ejabberd, MUC, MAM and a bit of customization, you can get very close to the same behaviour.

Comment: Now I can use "XEP-0048: Bookmarks" to store user's groups that he has joined. But I can not get the member list who has joined the group(no matter the user is online or offline.)